# how can i make page transition animation work in next js and framer motion?

Tags: animation, next.js, framer-motion, page-transition

so the problem is when user clicks on navbar link (for example on contact page when current opened page is home) when window is > 0 before animations start router.push is executed and it automatically scrolls to top creating weird movement and then animation start executing.

In my code i tried solutions like adding onExitComplete to my animatePresence component and also disabling link to scroll to top automatically

```
 <AnimatePresence
    mode="wait"
    onExitComplete={() => {
      if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        window.scrollTo({ top: 0 });
      }
    }}
  >
    <motion.div key={router.pathname} className="">
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <SlideUp pathname={pathname} />
      <SlideDown pathname={pathname} />
    </motion.div>
  </AnimatePresence>
```

and link

```
 {navItems.map((link, index) => (
        <motion.div variants={menuLinkVars} key={index}>
          <p suppressHydrationWarning onClick={() => handleClick(link)}>
            {link.title}
          </p>
        </motion.div>
  ))}

const handleClick = (link) => {
active.setActiveLink(link.title);

router.push(link.href, {
  scroll: false,
});
```

};

maybe the main problem is on styling my SlideDown /SlideUp div

```
  <motion.div
  className="absolute text-white bottom-0 left-0 w-full h-full bg-black origin-top"
  initial={{ scaleY: 1 }}
  animate={{ scaleY: 0 }}
  exit={{
    scaleY: 0,
  }}
  transition={{ duration: 0.8, ease: [0.76, 0, 0.24, 1], delay: 0.2 }}
>
  <h1 suppressHydrationWarning>{active.activeLink}</h1>
</motion.div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I menage to fix the issue by adding position fixed instead of absolute in animations divs, I think i will keep this question for others so that they can implement page transitions in nextjs because it seems to be a bit tricky, also if any of you know how to implement page transitions in newewst app routing instead of old pages i would appreciate commment, thanks best regards!